# Sort ArrayList alphabetically by value after a comma in each String

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I have an ArrayList containing Strings that looks like this:

- Item1: Some text, Annabelle
- Item2: Some text, James
- Item3: Some text, Conner

I would like to sort the ArrayList alphabeticlly by the value after the comma in each String.

How can I achieve this?

```
    ArrayList<String> lineList = new ArrayList<>();

    // New BufferedReader.
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            file));

    // Add all lines from file to ArrayList.
    while (true) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            break;
        }
        lineList.add(line);
    }

    // Close it.
    reader.close();

    // Print each line.
    for (String line : lineList) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

Comment: Is your file 'csv'? If yes then need to be careful because comma can be contained as part of the value like "'Some,text', Annabelle".

Comment: No, it is a txt file but yes I understand the concerns there. Thanks!

Comment: If you have large file size then it would be convenient to create already sorted list instead of sorting it in the memory. See my answer.

Comment: Okay, I will make some time to test it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("zzz, abc");
        list.add("yy, ghi");
        list.add("x, def");
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
                return filter(lhs).compareTo(filter(rhs));
            }

            private String filter(String s) {
                // consider the first comma
                return s.replaceFirst("^.*?, ", "");
                // to consider the last comma instead:
                // return s.replaceFirst("^.*, ", "");
            }
        });
        for (String s : list)
            System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
zzz, abc
x, def
yy, ghi
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) with the [`Collections.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) method.

For example:

```
Collections.sort(lineList, new Comparator<String>{
    public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
        String actual1 = str1.split(",")[1];
        String actual2 = str2.split(",")[1];

        return actual1.compare(actual2);
    }
});
```

You may want some way to ensure that you actually extract the correct part of the string, in case there is zero or multiple commas. You can for example use `substring()` in combination with `lastIndexOf()` as IQV mentioned.

Comment: "You may want some way to ensure..." Or if the only comma is at the end, e.g. `Foo,`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a one liner using Java 8:

```
lineList.sort((String s1, String s2) -> s1.split(",")[1].compareTo(s2.split(",")[1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not sort list after its populating, sort it on the fly:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Set<String> lines = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.substring(o.indexOf(','))));

        // New BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sample.txt"));

        // Add all lines from file to ArrayList.
        while (true) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            lines.add(line);
        }

        // Close it.
        reader.close();

        // Print each line.
        for (String line : lines) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner variant using Java 8:

```
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(s -> s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(","), s.length())));
```

or shorter

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(s -> s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(","), s.length())));
```

Answer (score 0):

As jesper mentioned, you need a Comparator. In this Comparator identitfy the forname with the method `lastIndexOf(',')`.